# Broadcast video file (not video from ip camera) from server to web page

Tags: c#, angular, typescript

In the folder on the server is the downloaded / recorded video file in MP4 format. I need to remotely connect to the server and play the file on the client page.

```
>On client. ts:

export class VideoLayoutPartComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() part: LayoutPart;
  videoSource: SafeUrl;

  constructor(private httpService: HttpService, private configurationService: ConfigurationService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.configurationService.configurationUpdated.subscribe(() => this.configurationUpdated());
  }

  private configurationUpdated() {
    return this.httpService.get('configuration/getVideo?videoUID='+ this.part.properties['referenceUID']).subscribe(videoData => {
      this.videoSource = videoData;
    });
  }

>On client. html:

<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls" preload="auto">
    <source src="{{videoSource}}}" type="video/mp4">
</video>

>On server

Configuration.cs:

    [HttpGet]
    public BitArray GetVideo(Guid? videoUid)
    {
        return VideoFactory.GetVideo(videoUid);
    }

VideoFactory.cs:

public static BitArray GetVideo(Guid? videoUID)
{
    if (videoUID.HasValue && videoUID != Guid.Empty)
    {
      foreach (var fileInfo in contentFolder.GetFiles())
      {
    if (Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileInfo.FullName) == videoUID.ToString())
      {
         byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fileInfo.FullName);
         return new BitArray(bytes);
          }
       }
     }
}
```

The reference UID comes from the client, the server finds the video, successfully processes it in the byte array and sends it back. But the client does not perceive the bytes and the browser freezes. Please help me understand how to accept an array by the client and play the video.

Comment: try making the http request as `responseType: 'blob'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem like this:

On client. html:

```
<div class="main">
    <video playsinline controlsList="nodownload" controls autoplay [src]="videoSource">
        videoSource error
    </video>
</div>
```

On client. ts:

```
export class VideoLayoutPartComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() part: LayoutPart;
  videoSource: SafeUrl;

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer, private httpService: HttpService, private configurationService: ConfigurationService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.configurationService.configurationUpdated.subscribe(() => this.configurationUpdated());
  }

  private configurationUpdated() {
    return this.httpService.get<string>('configuration/getVideo?videoUID=' + this.part.properties['referenceUID']).subscribe(result => {
      this.videoSource = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('data:video/mp4;base64,' + result);
    });
  }
}
```

On server

```
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult GetVideo(Guid? videoUid)
        {
            return Json(VideoFactory.GetVideo(videoUid));
        }
```

```
    public class VideoFactory
    {
        public static string GetVideo(Guid? videoUID)
        {
            var contentFolder = new DirectoryInfo(AppDataFolderHelper.GetFolder("Server/Config/Resources"));
            if (videoUID.HasValue && videoUID != Guid.Empty)
            {
                foreach (var fileInfo in contentFolder.GetFiles())
                {
                    if (Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileInfo.FullName) == videoUID.ToString())
                        return Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(fileInfo.FullName));
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```